# Adding IBOutlet UIView to array during init

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, initialization, nsarray, iboutlet

I'm getting a bit confused with UIViews recently, I have been using them fine up until this point and they are just refusing to be compliant!

I have a UIViewController, and this contains 5 different views. I have created IBOutlets for these views as I am wanting to swap them at runtime:

```
IBOutlet UIView *view1;
IBOutlet UIView *view2;
IBOutlet UIView *view3;
IBOutlet UIView *view4;
IBOutlet UIView *view5;
```

To make them easier to maintain I decided to keep them all within an array, called viewArray. Now I am trying to add the views to the array as follows:

```
viewArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:view1, view2, view3, view4, nil];
```

This is being called in the init function of my UIViewController class. I have linked up all the IBOutlets to their relevant views in the xib / interface file, but they do not appear to be initialized. Upon further debugging it looks like the views aren't initialized until after the init function is called?

So how can I create an array of these objects? I will need to select the relevant view before the view itself is shown, therefore viewDidLoad is not an option.

I know that you can grab the tags of things and implicitly set them using:

```
imageExample = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:100];
```

But can this be used to find views, as surely it will be searching for the tags within the originally initialized view (view1)?

Thanks for any help in advanced,
Kind Regards,
Elliott

Comment: Where does the `viewArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects...` statement appear in your code? Is it your `init` method?

Comment: I assume that the values of `IBOutlet` variables are set to non-nil by the time you need to access them for the first time, right?

Comment: Yes that's the issue currently, besides coming up with a hack I can't think of a way to populate the array before viewDidLoad is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize the `viewArray` lazily, for the price of having to use `self.viewArray` instead of unqualified `viewArray`.

Here is how you can do it:

In the .h file:

```
NSArray* _viewArray;

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *viewArray;
```

In the .m file:

```
-(NSArray*) viewArray {
    if (!_viewArray) {
        _viewArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:view1, view2, view3, view4, nil];
    }
    return _viewArray;
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between self.viewArray and viewArray? How does this code work exactly, if you wouldn't mind explaining it I would be grateful :)

Comment: @ElliottD'Alvarez `self.viewArray` is a method call expressed using the property syntax; `viewArray` would be a reference of an instance variable. Every time you reference `self.viewArray`, for example in a method call like this `[self.viewArray objectAtIndex:i]` the `viewArray` method gets invoked. It checks the variable _viewArray for being assigned. The first time around it is set to `nil`, so the `if` statement body will be executed, and the `_viewArray` instance variable is going to get set. In subsequent calls the `_viewArray` will not be `nil`, and will be returned to the caller.